Predatory trading as a game of size
I asked this question on quant.stackexchange and didn't receive an answer. I was advised to ask here as well. Predatory trading has been addressed in literature frequently. I have read for example Brunnemeier (2005) but that paper mostly addresses predatory trading surrounding a preexisting distressed trader. I am interested in the specific case of solvent trader(s) being forced towards liquidation by a predatory counterparty, where the solvent trader(s) fights back by using sidelined capital to maintain their position / recollateralize.
The best example of this I can give is this GameStop incident, where a large group of retail traders tried to liquidate the shorts (the distressed traders) but the many of the shorts used access to lines of credit / capital reserves to maintain their positions, and it basically became a game of size since whoever had more capital could force a bad trade. This is not really well addressed afaik, because most of papers assume predators and distressed traders have perfect information, and that the distressed traders are already forced to execute. My observation is that in reality the execution of successful predatory trading seems to depend on knowledge of how much sidelined capital there is. And of course, knowing exactly how much capital is in reserve is impossible. Despite all this, I have seen this strategy deployed frequently, where whales will execute large sells or buys over time to push the price and flush leverage out.
My question then is, is there some way to surmount this problem so that this game of size is an actual viable strategy? Are there any papers that address this quantitatively?

Hi: I don't know about predatory but the 2007 meltdown in intraday stat arb ( I forget what month. it was late 2007 ) was supposedly due to one large hedge fund liquidation. Andrew Lo has a paper on this topic and maybe there are references in that paper. Unfortunately, it was not a case of the hedge fund being predatory.
